# Updating my workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a Workbook that is used in various different computers.
Sometimes I add features to it and I would like to easily update it.
The idea is whenever I have a new version of it, I take it to a new computer, save in a temp file and copy the sheets where the data is stored.

Based on the answers I have edit my first draft to: (I didn't know that both workbooks needed to be opened at the same time)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wn As Workbook
Set wn = Workbooks("Reception")
Set wb = Workbooks("Reception2")

With wb
  .Sheets("Pass").Range("A1") = "flh"

  For Each ws In .Worksheets
    Select Case .Name
            Case "Formularios", "Coordenador", "LookupList", "Pass"
               'Do nothing
            Case Else
                ws.Delete
    End Select
  Next ws
End With

With wn
  For Each sh In .Worksheets
    Select Case .Name
        Case "Formularios", "Coordenador", "LookupList", "Pass"
        'Do nothing
        Case Else
            sh.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
    End Select
  Next sh
End With

End Sub
```

Case at moment is not working and macro deletes every sheet no matter the name

Thank you all for the feedback

Comment: Probably start by Googling the VBA `Workbooks` and `Workbook` objects as well as the VBA error itself.

Comment: You don't need all those IF statements. Use one IF with AND or store the sheet names in array and check not in array then.....

Comment: Should `Reception.xlsm` be in the temp folder or save folder - or are they two separate files with the same name - in which case you can't have them both open at the same time.

Comment: @ashleedawg that's the first thing I did

Comment: @qharr I don't like the "and" statement, and prefer to code with the if's I know that this makes it longer, though I get the job done.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook They are two separate files. Didn't know they had to be both opened. changed one of their names. thanks

Comment: Have a look at the `Select Case` statement in my answer if you don't like the `and` statement.  If the sheet name is the same as one of the ones in the case statement then nothing happens (as is commented in the code), otherwise (`else`) the sheet is deleted.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook I have cleaned the code as you requested. Still I get the same error. If you see the other comment I wrote, both the files are opened and are at the correct locations.

Comment: You'll still get the error - code is just easier to read.   I'll update my answer to take account of new info.

Comment: Just realised - if the workbook is open you don't need that path, just the name.  Can't believe I didn't see that!  `Set wn = Workbooks("Reception.xlsm")` - although I'm not sure if it has to be the name as it appears in the title bar (i.e. remove the extension if not shown in your settings).

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook sorry to be a pain but I have never worked with case before. I googled a little and it apparently it should do nothing, however now with your change of the set part. It started deleting everything, doesn't matter the name

Comment: Not sure what part you mean with the _change of the set part_.  All the `Select Case` should do is check the worksheet name (`ws.name`) on each loop.  If the name _exactly_ matches one of the names in the `case` statement it should perform that code block (`'Do nothing`) otherwise it will perform the `Else` action (`ws.Delete`).

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook The comment before mine you said to change the path using set. So I did. Now it appears the code is working, however it deletes every single sheet

Comment: Took me a minute to figure out what was wrong there (yep, deleted everything when I copied your code).  `Select Case .Name` is using the `With wb` line - so it's referring to the workbook name rather than the worksheet name, use `Select Case ws.Name` instead.

Comment: Never mind... it did what it was suppose to after I twinked the code a little My issue is different now.. The formulas in the 4 sheets that were not deleted became #Ref. I googled a little maybe its better for me to do a "Clear contents" on each sheet and then copy only the contents making sure each will go to the right place.. will have to google more..

Comment: Yep, those formula will do that if they reference the sheets you deleted.  You could remove the formula leaving just the values - either copy & pastespecial or `Range("A1") = Range("A1")` will do the trick, but that's another question.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the temp folder by using `Environ("temp")`, but from your code I'm not sure this is the folder you're using.

This code has a couple of functions to check if the workbook exists and is already open.  One other bit of code I'd add is to disable any code in `Reception.xlsm` from firing when it's opened.

```
Public Sub MyProcedure()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wn As Workbook

    Dim Rec1Path As String
    Dim Rec2Path As String

    Rec1Path = "c:\save\Reception.xlsm"
    Rec2Path = "c:\temp\Reception2.xlsm"

    'Open or set a reference to Reception.xlsm.
    If WorkBookExists(Rec1Path) Then
        If WorkBookIsOpen(Rec1Path) Then
            'Don't need path for open workbook, just name.
            'InStrRev finds last occurrence of "\" (same as InStr, but in Reverse).
            Set wn = Workbooks(Mid(Rec1Path, InStrRev(Rec1Path, "\") + 1))
        Else
            Set wn = Workbooks.Open(Rec1Path)
        End If
    End If

    'Open or set a reference to Reception2.xlsm.
    If WorkBookExists(Rec2Path) Then
        If WorkBookIsOpen(Rec2Path) Then
            Set wb = Workbooks(Mid(Rec2Path, InStrRev(Rec2Path, "\") + 1))
        Else
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Rec2Path)
        End If
    End If

    With wb
        .Worksheets("Pass").Range("A1") = "flh"

        For Each ws In .Worksheets
            Select Case .Name
                Case "Formularios", "Coordenador", "LookupList", "Pass"
                    'Do nothing
                Case Else
                    'You don't really need the count of worksheets if you can guarantee
                    'you're not going to try and delete the last remaining sheet.
                    If .Worksheets.Count > 1 Then
                        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                        ws.Delete
                        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                    End If
            End Select
        Next ws
    End With

    With wn
        'Re-using the ws variable.
        For Each ws In .Worksheets
            Select Case .Name
                Case "Formularios", "Coordenador", "LookupList", "Pass"
                    'Do nothing
                Case Else
                    ws.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
            End Select
        Next ws
    End With

End Sub

Public Function WorkBookExists(sPath As String) As Boolean
    WorkBookExists = Dir(sPath) <> ""
End Function

Public Function WorkBookIsOpen(FullFilePath As String) As Boolean

    Dim ff As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    ff = FreeFile()
    Open FullFilePath For Input Lock Read As #ff
    Close ff
    WorkBookIsOpen = (Err.Number <> 0)

    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Comment: it's not windows temp. Just a "Temp" folder i created in C.

Comment: In that case it's probably as @Xabier states - is the file already open or does the code need to open it?  On top of that - are you relying on the user to create the folders and save the workbooks in there with the correct names?  If so I'd suggest the problem is probably between the computer and chair (also known as an _ID10T_ error).

Answer (score 0):

Is the workbook open when you try to 'SET' it? If not you will need to open it as such:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open("c:\temp\Reception.xlsm")
```

Answer (score 0):

With some more googling I was able to craft the code that I wanted in the end.
Here is the answer for the curious or for other people looking to do the same:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() 
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim Rng As Range
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wn As Workbook
Set wn = Workbooks("Reception")
Set wb = Workbooks("Reception2")

With wb
  .Sheets("Pass").Range("A1") = "flh"

  For Each ws In .Worksheets
    Select Case ws.Name
            Case "Formularios"
                'Do nothing
            Case "Coordenador"
                'Do nothing
            Case "LookupList"
                'Do nothing
            Case "Pass"
                'Do nothing
            Case Else
                 With ws
                    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                    Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
                    Rng.ClearContents
                End With
    End Select
  Next ws
End With

With wn
  For Each sh In .Worksheets
    Select Case sh.Name
            Case "Formularios"
                'Do nothing
            Case "Coordenador"
                'Do nothing
            Case "LookupList"
                'Do nothing
            Case "Pass"
                'Do nothing
            Case Else
                For j = 1 To wb.Sheets.Count
                    If sh.Name = wb.Worksheets(j).Name Then
                        On Error Resume Next
                            sh.Range("A:J").Copy wb.Worksheets(j).Range("A1")
                    End If
                Next j
    End Select
  Next sh
End With
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Thanks to @Darren Bartrup-Cook for the help.